# I have a problem with repleace / delete "." (dot) in a "Value" column. Hepl needed. #Python #Pandas #jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I prepared a Python dataframe using Pandas in Jupyther like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F3qv.png)

In the next step, I delete the '€' sign with:

`df = analyzed_df['Value'] = analyzed_df['Value'].str[1:]`

And then I replace the rest of the unnecessary characters:

`df = analyzed_df['Value'].replace(regex={'M': '00000','K': '000'})`

I have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STHzM.png)

As we can see, I have 2 problems:

1. I have an unnecessary period ('.')
2. I have a dtype as an object

I want to remove the problematic '.' And change dtype to int. I will be very grateful for tips on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to delete the dots and [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to change its dtype:

```
df.str.replace('.','').astype(int)
```